# Помогите найти ошибку в скрипте для создания таблице в PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

Использую такой скрипт:

```
tracker=# create table privilege_roles IF NOT EXISTS(                           
role char(10) PRIMARY KEY,                                                      
data_view boolean,                                                              
data_injection boolean                                                          
);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: create table privilege_roles IF NOT EXISTS(
```

Когда часть  `IF NOT EXISTS` вырезал все сработало. Почему так в чем ошибка, вроде все по докам? Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть вот так

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS privilege_roles(                           
    role char(10) PRIMARY KEY,                                                      
    data_view boolean,                                                              
    data_injection boolean                                                          
);
```